wrong physical ID in cloudformation
I have the problem when i try to continue rollback update, i receive an error that the specified function must exist before referencing it.

Resource handler returned message: "The specified functions [qu3opjwrbbas5fphogv6o5xc5i,klgmrt6o3zf7fcrdlnptvfi3su] must exist before referencing them from a resolver
The problem is that i indeed have create a appsync function, but it has a different ID then the ID defined in the stack. The stack expects klgmrt6o3zf7fcrdlnptvfi3su but mine is different, i dont know how to change the ID or how to change the reference, or where i need to search.

I am facing the same type of issue. Have you found the answer?

@ArupChaudhury well if you create the resources and it has a different ID then the template, then you either need to delete this resources or this stack where the resource is available, or you write an ticket to AWS to set the stack back to UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE and then you update the stack with a new template where you remove the failing resources

That is exactly what I did, update the stack with a new template. Thanks for your response.
